# How to Apply background image on Table in PDF using iText library?

Tags: java, itext

I am creating a PDF using the iText Library and not been able to set the background image for Table in PDF.

like below image[image]

**Edit**

Currently i am using this to set Background , its setting image to absolute position , i want to set it relative to table

```
class CellBackgroundPic  implements PdfPTableEvent {

Activity mActivity;
public CellBackgroundPic (Activity Activity){

    this.mActivity=Activity;

}
Image bgImage;


public void tableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] widths, float[] heights,
        int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvases){
    PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
    Drawable   myImage  = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.table_bg);

      Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) myImage).getBitmap();
       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
       byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
       try {
        bgImage = Image.getInstance(bitmapdata);
        bgImage.setAbsolutePosition(330f, 642f);
        pdfContentByte.addImage(bgImage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches possible.

One would be to use a pattern color created with an image and use that pattern color as background color. However, that doesn't seem to be a match with what you need.

Based on your example I would suggest using a table event as demonstrated here:
http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=93

In this example, the background color of the rows is drawn in the `tableLayout()` method. You need to adapt this method and instead of drawing colored rectangles, you need to add an image at the appropriate coordinates.

Comment: i do not want to Draw image on absolute position , how i set image according to table coordinate using Table event

Comment: Huh? Saying you don't want to draw an image on an absolute position is absurd! Did you read any of the documentation at all? Or are you just pulling my leg? In the table event, you get these values: float[][] widths, float[] heights. These arrays contain all the coordinates you need. You want to draw the image at an absolute position using the coordinates x = widths[0][0], y = heights[0] - image.getScaledHeight().